# Win32 process creation order

Tags: winapi

I would like to enumerate all the instances of an application and determine which instance was created first (oldest).  Given a list of HWNDs that belong to the process instances, can I sort the list to determine the order of creation?  If not, is there another way?

EDIT 1 : the windows being enumerated are not created by my process, they were created long before my process started execution.

EDIT 2: As mentioned in the comments, I am interested in the creation time of the processed.  I need the HWND of he main window of the oldest instance of the application.  Not sure how to get the HWND from the process ID.

Comment: [`GetProcessTimes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Alex, Thank you -- this looks promising.

Comment: `GetProcessTimes` will not return window creation times. Either the question is asking about something the author didn't mean to ask, or the suggestion doesn't match.

Comment: @IInspectable if the window in question is the app's main window, then it's creation time will be close to the process's creation time. But in any case, the OP is clearly looking for process creation time, but is using window enumeration to find the processes. I would have used process enumeration instead.

Comment: Please edit your question to have it ask for what you really want, especially the question title. Once done, this question should probably be reopened, since the duplicate does not apply, if @RemyLebeau is correct.

Comment: @Remy On a side note, there is no such thing as the "app's main window". First window created is not necessarily main window. It could be a splash screen with a very long duration for instance. Then creation time of the "main window" could be much different from process creation time. Other than that I basically agree.

Comment: In general, there is no solution to your *"EDIT 2"*, as briefly outlined by @zett42. Windows does not maintain the notion of a *"main window"*. You'll have to apply a custom heuristic to get a reference to the window, that's interesting to your application. It would probably help to explain, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish. As written, your question is really asking about your solution, rather than your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways you can approach this:

1. **Start with the windows**

   - Use `EnumWindows()`, or a `FindWindow/Ex()` loop, to find the candidate app windows you are interested in. In the case of `EnumWindows()`, you can use things like `GetClassName()` and `GetWindowText()` in the callback.
   - Use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get each window's PID.
   - Use `OpenProcess()` to open each PID, and `GetProcessTimes()` to get its creation time.
   - Now you can sort the times to get the oldest, and you will know the window(s) that go with the corresponding process.
2. **Start with the processes**

   - Use `EnumProcesses()`, or a `Process32(First|Next)()` loop, to find the PIDs of each instance of the app path+filename you are interested in.
   - Use `OpenProcess()` and `GetProcessTimes()` to get their creation times, and then sort them.
   - Then, with the oldest PID, you can enumerate windows looking for the one(s) that belong to that PID. You can either:

     1. enumerate all windows as above, using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to look for the PID.
     2. use `EnumThreadWindows()` on each thread of the process. To get the process's thread IDs, you can use a `Thread32(First|Next)()` loop.

        Optionally, assuming the process's main thread is the one creating the window(s) you want, you can limit the window enumeration to just that thread. Enumerate the pricess's threads, using `OpenThread()` and `GetThreadTimes()` to find the oldest thread ID, which will be the main thread.